# First and Last Index of occurrence of value in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array created in PHP as follows:

*`$arr = array(123,144,144,123);`*

How do I get the first and last indexes of occurrence of each value.
Something like,

```
123 -> first occurrence - 0th index | last occurrence - 3rd index
144 -> first occurrence - 1st index | last occurrence - 2nd index
```

Comment: what is `last - 3` and `last - 2` as per your example ?

Comment: Please elaborate the question more

Comment: array_search to get the key, unset in a copy, then another array_search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `array_search()`:

```
$arr = array(123,144,144,123);
$first = array_search(123, $arr); // 0
$last = array_search(123, array_reverse($arr, true)); // 3
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [1,2,2,3,1,2,3];

$result = [];

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){

    if(!in_array($array[$i],array_keys($result))){
        $result[$array[$i]] = ['first-occurance'=>$i,'last-occurance'=>$i];
    }

    for($j = $i+1; $j < sizeof($array); $j++){

        if($array[$i] == $array[$j]){

            $result[$array[$i]]['last-occurance'] = $j;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

OR by using `array_search()` "CREDITS to [Dan Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4471134/dan-miller)"

```
$result = [];

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){

    if(!in_array($array[$i],array_keys($result))){
        $result[$array[$i]] = ['first-occurance'=>array_search($array[$i],$array),'last-occurance'=>array_search($array[$i],array_reverse($array, true))];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```