# get min and max position in array where value exist

Tags: php

I need to find the min and max position into an array where some value exist!
use a loop inside a loop to compare values is not an option ( my array has 100.000 values )

e.g=

```
$myarray[0]="red";
$myarray[1]="red";
$myarray[2]="blue";
$myarray[3]="blue";
$myarray[4]="blue";
$myarray[5]="red";
```

how to get the min and max position where **blue** exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023793/first-and-last-index-of-occurrence-of-value-in-php-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second argument for `array_keys`:

```
if($blue = array_keys($myarray, 'blue')) {
    $min = min($blue);
    $max = max($blue);
}
```

Comment: This code will fail when the searched needle doesn't exist in the row.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: Good point, forgot that it was a warning and not false.

Comment: Yes, the use of `array_keys()` is a stroke of genius. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the search_value to extract all the matching keys, and then [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) to get the two ones that you want.

```
$keys = array_keys($myarray,'blue'); //[2,3,4]
$maxKey = max($keys); //4
$minKey = min($keys); //2
```

I have to advise that performance wise is better to do a for loop:

```
$length = count($myarray);
$minKey = FALSE;
$maxKey = FALSE;
$search = 'blue';
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
  if($myarray[$i] == $search){
    if($minKey === FALSE) $minKey = $i;
    $maxKey = $i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this is the answer?

```php
function getMinKey($arr, $search){
    if(!in_array($search, $arr)){
        return false;
    }

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if($value == $search){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

function getMaxKey($arr, $search){
    if(!in_array($search, $arr)){
        return false;
    }

    $arrCount = count($arr)-1;
    for($i = $arrCount; $i >=0; $i--){
        if($arr[$i] == $search){
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: posted it to sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6cece2be5e8731aa13a172c0e5d310cc73d7fa0e

Answer (score 0):

All solutions, so far, have searched the whole array, which might be quite inefficient. You only need to search from the start upto the first "blue" and from the end downto the last "blue". Like this:

```
$find  = "blue";
$first = false;
$last  = false;

$max = count($myarray);
$key = 0;
while ($key < $max) {
    if ($myarray[$key] == $find) {
        $first = $key;
        break;
    }
    $key++;
}
if ($first !== false) {
    $key = --$max;
    while ($key > 0) {
        if ($myarray[$key] == $find) {
            $last = $key;
            break;
        }
        $key--;
    }
}
```

Note that this code takes into account that nothing will be found. In that case `$first` and `$last` will contain `false`. It also checks to see if the `$first` was found to prevent searching through the array twice when there's clearly no need for that.

Comment: Maybe you want to start from `$max-1` in the second loop

Comment: @salvatore Good idea! :-)